# Is this a valid proof of the parallel postulate?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let x<sub>1</sub> be a line with a slope of tan(n) where `0 ≤ n < π/2`.

> x<sub>1</sub> = tan((π/2)-n)y, 0 < n ≤ π/2

Let y<sub>2</sub> be a line with a slope of tan(m) where `-π/2 < m ≤ 0`; that has a y-intercept at b.

> x<sub>2</sub> = tan((π/2)+m)y + b, -π/2 ≤ m < 0

Can we use systems of equations to prove that there will be a solution when the interior angles(n and m) don't add up to π/2?

**When n = π/2, and m = π/2:**

The angles add up to π.

> x<sub>1</sub> = tan((π/2)-π/2)y
>
> x<sub>1</sub> = 0
>
> x<sub>2</sub> = tan((π/2)+π/2)y + b
>
> x<sub>2</sub> = b

Solving for the solution of the system:

> 0 ≠ b, no solutions

[Desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBuJl.png)

**When π/2 > n > 0, and m = π/2:**

Angles add upto to less than π.

> x<sub>1</sub> = tan((π/2)-n)y
>
> x<sub>2</sub> = tan((π/2)+π/2)y + b = b

Solving for the solution of the system:

> tan((π/2)-n)y = b
>
> y = b/tan((π/2)-n), one solution

[Desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwYQ5.png)

**When π/2 > n > 0, and π/2 > m > 0:**

Angles add upto to less than π.

> x<sub>1</sub> = tan((π/2)-n)y
>
> x<sub>2</sub> = tan((π/2)+m)y + b

Solving for the solution of the system:

> tan((π/2)-n)y = tan((π/2)+m)y + b
>
> tan((π/2)-n)y - tan((π/2)+m)y = b
>
> y(tan((π/2)-n) - tan((π/2)+m)) = b
>
> y = b/(tan((π/2)-n) - tan((π/2)+m)), one solution

[Desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1Sl.png)

**When n = π/2, and π/2 > m > 0:**

The angles add up to less than π.

> x<sub>1</sub> = tan((π/2)-π/2)y
>
> x<sub>1</sub> = 0
>
> x<sub>2</sub> = tan((π/2)+m)y + b

Solving for the solution of the system:

> 0 = tan((π/2)+m)y + b
>
> y = -b/tan((π/2)+m), one solution

[Desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8EES.png)

Does this prove that there will be a solution when the interior angles don't add up to π?

Interactive graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/laijd4spwx

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right from the beginning you speak about lines with particular slopes. But this assumes that you have a rectangular coordinate system to measure the slopes with, and in order to construct such a coordinate system, *you need the parallel postulate already*.

So your argument does not work as a "proof of the parallel postulate" in the usual sense of a proof that start from the other axioms of Euclidean plane geometry.

Something like your calculations (which I haven't checked in detail) will prove that if we start by *defining* the plane to be $\mathbb R^2$ with certain operations, then that plane happens to satisfy the parallel postulate. This can definitely be a relevant thing to prove when you want to argue that analytic geometry *works* in the first place, or that Euclidean geometry is *consistent* relative to our usual foundations (such as ZFC).

It's just not the problem that "proof of the parallel postulate" is usually taken to be about.

Comment: Is there any references on the consistency of euclidean, analytic, riemannian, etc geometries?

Comment: Why does a rectangular coordinate system require the parallel postulate?